# How to track offline conversion with Facebook Marketing API without email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

So, basically I want track offline purchases by Facebook ad visitors. By reading the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/offline-conversions/v2.8) I discovered that you are supposed to have either an email or phone number to import a conversion.

But what if I don't have those? Client side conversion tracking (with JS snippet) doesn't require such information and is still able to properly attribute them to the right ad visitor (by using a  third-party cookie I guess).

Am I getting it wrong, or I am bound to loose half of my user conversions simply because the visitor's Facebook email is different from the one I have in the database.

Google Adwords offers the concept of GCLID, which is basically adwords visitor ID that you store in the database and later import conversions using it. Is there something similar for Facebook Marketing API (maybe some smart hack).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook defines "Offline Conversions" as transactions that happen outside of a web or app environment, such as in a retail store. Therefore JS snippets aren't available, and (hashed) identifier matching is necessary. E-mail and Phone aren't required, though you can imagine they might be easier to match than other keys. The full list of keys available for matching is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions/v2.9#api-flow (search for "match_keys") and includes name, date of birth, city, state, zip, country and mobile advertising identifier.

If you are in a web environment, you can report conversions via the [Facebook pixel's Purchase event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference#events). If you are in a mobile environment, you can report conversions via the Purchase [App Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events).